# clear view of box model

Tags: html, css

As far as i know every element in HTML associated with padding(left, right, top, bottom) , margin(left, right, top, bottom) which will create the box model for that so that we can figure it out its actual position with respect to document.

any idea over it?

Comment: hi Kenny i m asking about the css box model...you must be aware of it..

Comment: You are correct that all boxes in CSS have a certain amount of padding and margin, but I do not understand what question you are asking about it.

Comment: yes i want to know what all thing need to take in consideration when we are talking about box model.

Answer (score 3):

Don't really see a question.. but http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html explains the box model very very thoroughly.